# org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in [...]

Tags: jboss, wsdl, axis, stub

I'm dealing with this issue:
I generated the service stubs using Axis 1.4, with 1.4-redhat-1 as lib to the project.

I read a lot about this error and people said the issue was from the axis stubs generation itself, and the only solution was to regenerate stubs and recompile the projects that consumes them. The thing is: I made a test class in the and called the operation on eclipse using the "old" class without the new element and it works!

After that I copy/paste the test class to the main project that consumes the stubs, and it also worked.

But when I deploy the artifact to jBoss AS 5.1, I got the same "Invalid element" exception, so I'm guessing there's something "wrong" with the jBoss configs.

Does anyone have a tip where to start searching for the fix ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend not using axis and instead use Apache cxf as thats what the newer versions of JBoss are using.  Do you know how to change it to use the Jboss CXF (I think its wsdl2java) instead of using axis?  What version of jboss/wildfly or JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: As the stubs are working fine locally(eclipse java app), I don't think this has something to do with the stubs generation.

Comment: How are you interacting with them, e.g. calling them from a main method for testing or deploying them in a local copy of JBoss running on your dev box?  Testing from a main method, you'd think it would be using the axis built into eclipse but once deployed it would fail?

Comment: Did both, in a main method it worked, but won't work deployed in my jBoss.